# How php uses Http post request to assign $_POST?

Tags: php, json, http, http-headers, http-post

1) I want to know how `php` reads data from `Http post` request and puts them in `$_POST`.
what are the roles of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` and `multipart/form-data` 
in this action.

2) I just want to know why when I use `JSON` it makes my `$_POST` be empty but when I use `form` it fills it up.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I think I must add below line to make it be clearer:

I want to know why json in the body of Http post is not parsed and i must use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

There are mostly two types of method using in forms GET and POST

GET uses values of var from url 
POST get value of var from var for example

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type=text name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 

$variable= $_POST['name'];

echo $variable . " Welcome to this page ";

?>
```

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded** : all the spaces in form is converted to + and special chracters are converted to hex.

**application/json** : all values are converted in json and this enctype accepts json submission also

**multipart/form-data** : regulr form submission used to upload files

> and i already told you _POST get values from variables and form name
>   my above answer is for just example